# what the location of the folder packages when installing npm directive

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to install the "@ngui"- folder packages of angular.

It downloaded the folder, but when I try to install the folder in the cmd like this:

```
@ngui/ngui @types/googlemaps @types/hammerjs --save-dev
```

I got this error:

> npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@4.4.3 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.3 but none was installed.
>
> npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\moshel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-27T07_39_55_977Z-debug.log
>   PS C:\Users\moshel\Workspaces\Aman.Magar.Maply\WebUI> npm install @ngui/dist/ngui @types/googlemaps @types/hammerjs --save-dev

Maybe this is because the folder is not in the correct location?
Does anyone know where I need to put the folder that I downloaded?

Comment: It looks like your `ngui` is missing a dependency. have you tried npm ? `npm install @ngui/ngui --save-dev` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngui/ngui)

Comment: sorry, i dont was wright the full line.   this is was the line:   npm install @ngui/ngui @types/googlemaps @types/hammerjs --save-dev.                 and i was get this error

Comment: Check out this question, see if it is applicable to your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817571/npm-install-multiple-package-names